# How to have the name of all sections on the top of each page in this Beamer template?

Tags: beamer, presentations

This TeX should have about 10 sections each of which has a couple of subsections under it. Also, the names of sections are all 2-words. So in this Beamer template, as you can see, the names of all sections should appear in the black stripe on the top of each page. But because the number of my sections are too many, some of them are omitted by the template. How can I fix this so that I have the name of all sections on the top of each page?

```
 \documentclass[
    aspectratio=169
]{beamer}

\usetheme{Darmstadt}        

\begin{document}

\section{Descriptive Outline 1}
\subsection{Outline}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\end{frame}
\section{Descriptive Outline 2}
\subsection{Outline}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\end{frame}
\section{Descriptive Outline 3}
\subsection{Outline}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\end{frame}
\section{Descriptive Outline 4}
\subsection{Outline}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\end{frame}
\section{Descriptive Outline 5 }
\subsection{Outline}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\end{frame}
\section{Descriptive Outline 6}
\subsection{Outline}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\end{frame}
\section{Descriptive Outline 7}
\subsection{Outline}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\end{frame}
\section{Descriptive Outline 8}
\subsection{Outline}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\end{frame}
\section{Descriptive Outline 9}
\subsection{Outline}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\end{frame}
\section{Descriptive Outline 10}
\subsection{Outline}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you show a MWE that reproduces the problem, i.e. shows how long the sections names are and how much squeezing is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Squeezing an elephant into a suitcase is always difficult. One way to get a bit more space in the headline is to use another aspect ratio for the slide, e.g. 16:9.

Some other comments:

- the `\author{hh}` in front of the documentclass does nothing, you are overwriting it in your document
- you don't need `\usepackage{graphicx}` with beamer
- please don't load the same package multiple times. Anyway the more beamerish way would be to write `\usetheme{Darmstadt}`

---

```
\documentclass[
    aspectratio=169
]{beamer}

\usetheme{Darmstadt}        

\begin{document}

\section{Outline}
\subsection{Outline}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\end{frame}
\section{Outline}
\subsection{Outline}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\end{frame}
\section{Outline}
\subsection{Outline}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\end{frame}
\section{Outline}
\subsection{Outline}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\end{frame}
\section{Outline}
\subsection{Outline}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\end{frame}
\section{Outline}
\subsection{Outline}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\end{frame}
\section{Outline}
\subsection{Outline}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\end{frame}
\section{Outline}
\subsection{Outline}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\end{frame}
\section{Outline}
\subsection{Outline}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\end{frame}
\section{Outline}
\subsection{Outline}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

If the sections still don't fit in the headline, then there is simply not enough space and either another theme should be used or the amount of information in the headline should be reduced.

If the font size is further decreased to accommodate all the sections, it get so small, nobody will be able to read it anyway.

```
 \documentclass[
    aspectratio=169
]{beamer}


\usetheme{Darmstadt}        

\setbeamerfont{section in head/foot}{size=\fontsize{4pt}{5pt}\selectfont}


\begin{document}

\section{Descriptive Outline 1}
\subsection{Outline}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\end{frame}
\section{Descriptive Outline 2}
\subsection{Outline}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\end{frame}
\section{Descriptive Outline 3}
\subsection{Outline}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\end{frame}
\section{Descriptive Outline 4}
\subsection{Outline}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\end{frame}
\section{Descriptive Outline 5 }
\subsection{Outline}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\end{frame}
\section{Descriptive Outline 6}
\subsection{Outline}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\end{frame}
\section{Descriptive Outline 7}
\subsection{Outline}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\end{frame}
\section{Descriptive Outline 8}
\subsection{Outline}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\end{frame}
\section{Descriptive Outline 9}
\subsection{Outline}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\end{frame}
\section{Descriptive Outline 10}
\subsection{Outline}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. But 2 section named omitted in the headline yet. Can I still find more room?

Comment: @user157323 Post an example that reproduces your problem

Comment: Example posted by editing the question.

Comment: @user157323 Edited, even if I don't think it is a good idea

Comment: What is the most Beamerish font and font size?

Comment: @user157323 For text, the default size is 11pt using latex default font in sans serif

Comment: Is that font size normally visible enough in presentation? Also, because subitems were in smaller size, I have defined \large for subitems. Is \large for subitems the same as 11pt? What concerns me is if now the font size for my subitems is the same as the font size for other texts in my Beamer?

Comment: @user157323 As the name tells you `\large` is larger than the normal text font.